# Error with Curses on Raspberry Pi - Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, curses, python-curses

I've recently bought a Raspberry Pi and I'm completely new to Linux and Python. I'm trying to build a program that will enable to control the frequency of a flashing light with the arrow keys. So I found a related question with a solution [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=41195). I've used the sample code given to adapt it to my situation, but when I run the code, an error interrupts the runtime :

```
_curses.error : cbreak() returned ERR
```

I can't figure it out why is this happening. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you give more details?  The program you're running (possibly reduced, but not necessarily); the full traceback; and also whether the same program works on a regular PC or not.

Comment: @ArminRigo I actually didn't try to run it on another computer - to be honest I don't have Python on another one - but the code is almost the same as in the link I gave (I've just added a few lines in the if-else blocks).

Comment: @ArminRigo Damn I figured it out. It's just that this doesn't work with Idle... It works perfectly on Terminal. Thanks though